# MYSQL - How can I bin or group data based on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a database table that contains commodity trade information in a simple format: From_Country, To_Country, Year, Commodity, Trade_Volume.

I would like to create a table of ranked trading partners based on their trade history:  The conditions need to be:

- If Trade_Volume = 0 for a Commodity between From_Country 1 and To_Country 1 for all years, ranking = 0
- If Trade_Volume >0 for a Commodity From_Country 1 and To_Country 1 for years, 3, 4, and 5 then ranking = 1

Does anyone have ideas that may help me?

Comment: You really, really should do some research on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Trade_Volume = 0 AND From_Country = 1 AND To_Country = 1 THEN 0 
            WHEN Trade_Volume > 0 AND From_Country = 1 AND To_Country = 1 AND Year IN (3,4,5) THEN 1
END AS Ranking
FROM <yourtable>
```